# Magento Mail Up Extension Compilation Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, compilation

when I active the compilation on magento I've this error with Mailup. Any ideas on how to make it work with compilation?

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/mydomain/public_html/inoxwhere/includes/Model/MailUpWsImport.php' (include_path='/home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain/includes/src:.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in /home/mydomain/public_html/mydomain/includes/src/MailUp_MailUpSync_Helper_Data.php on line 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't solve your issue, I would highly recommend avoiding the compilation tool built into Magento.. consider using a cache like redis and you'll see a noticeable performance improvement - the compiler actually doesn't improve performance whatsoever with the updates made to PHP since it was released.

Just incase you're unable to disable compilation, go to /includes/config.php and comment out both lines at the bottom with a # and delete the src folder or rename it.

Hope this helps